# RubyInline C extension - pthread_create calls ruby function

Tags: c, ruby

I am trying to apply C multithreading to a ruby method but I am not able to call the ruby method properly. I am just testing one thread for now and I am not passing any parameters just to keep things simple.

Here is the code

```
require 'inline'

class ExampleThread

def my_thread
    puts 'running thread';
end

inline :C do |builder|
    builder.include "<pthread.h>"
    builder.c '
    static VALUE run_thread(void){
        ID my_thread    = rb_intern("my_thread");

        pthread_t pth;

        // normal ruby function call
        // rb_funcall(self, my_thread, 0);
        // but I want to try with threads
        pthread_create(&pth,NULL,my_thread,NULL);

        pthread_join(pth, NULL);

        return Qnil;
    }'
end

end
```

and here is the error

```
warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

### # => EDIT

Reading your comments I decided to change the code and here is what I came up with so far.

```
require 'inline'

class Example

  inline :C do |builder|
  builder.include "<pthread.h>"

    builder.c '
    static void run_thread(VALUE name){
        // I added a ruby User class to test posting a variable from thread to db
        VALUE user = rb_const_get( rb_cObject, rb_intern("User") );         
        rb_funcall(user, rb_intern("add"), 1, name);
    }'


    builder.c '
    static void simple(VALUE name){
        run_thread(self, name);
    }'      


    builder.c '
    static void threads(VALUE name){
        pthread_t pth;

        pthread_create(&pth, NULL, (void *)run_thread, (VALUE *)name );

        pthread_join(pth, NULL);
    }'              
end     

end
```

if I run Example.new.run_thread("Adam") i get the expected result

```
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
SQL (19.9ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`, `name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2012-03-16 04:53:15', 'Adam', '2012-03-16 04:53:15')
(0.5ms)  COMMIT
```

if I run Example.new.simple("Adam") I get the expected result

```
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
SQL (19.9ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`, `name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2012-03-16 04:53:15', 'Adam', '2012-03-16 04:53:15')
(0.5ms)  COMMIT
```

if I run Example.new.threads("Adam") i get the error

```
[FATAL] failed to allocate memory
```

My understanding is that I have to ALLOC memory in order to get the expected result but this process is not quite clear to me and I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: You need to pass a c function pointer, not a ruby method name. I'm also not sure whether there is some per-thread setup you need to do for it to work with the ruby runtime

Answer (score 0):

I dono ruby. What you mentioned is just a warning. So the object file will be generated. Run it. It may work fine as you expected. The warning says just a casting issue. So explicitly cast my_thread to a void pointer and compile.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I also get a Segmentation fault. I tired with (void) and produces error: invalid use of void expression.

Comment: ID my_thread    = rb_intern("my_thread");    I feel this line is a function call and you are assigning the return value back to my_thread. If I'm correct, the call to pthread_create is false. you have to pass a function pointer not a return value.